# What is the corresponding FACS Action unit name to the Affdex Emotion SDK expressions output?

Tags: computer-vision, affdex-sdk, emotion

I wonder where I can find a full list of Action Unit names which are detected from Affdex? I have manually identified some: browfurrow (AU4),  browraise (AU2),  chinraise (AU17). However, an [official information document](http://developer.affectiva.com/metrics) will be a better choice for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We follow the same FACS system for naming the AU's, you can find the list of Action Units on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_Action_Coding_System). For a more visual representation you can refer to [Academic Pages](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~face/facs.htm).

Comment: Thank you! However, there are 3 outputs from Affdex that I could not match with both Wikipedia and Academic Pages: eye widen, smile, and smirk. Are these not official AUs?

Comment: * Smile doesn't correspond to an AU, the closest is AU 12 (lip corner puller). The smile classifier evaluates texture features from the whole face not just the lip area.

In some cases, we tried to use simpler names to represent the actions than what is defined in the literature:

* Eye widen is Upper Lid Raiser (AU 5)
* Smirk is defined in the literature as "asymmetric lip corner puller"